# Emaling with apps script to non-gmail accounts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
function onSubmit(e) {
//.......  
var NewSpreadSheetID = NewSpreadSheet.getId();
var File = Drive.Files.get(NewSpreadSheetID);
var url = File.exportLinks[MimeType.CSV];
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
}
});

var blobs = [response.getBlob().setName(DirectoryName)];




if (EmailBoolean == "yes") {
var UserEmail = e.response.getResponseForItem(frm[130]).getResponse().toString();
var CreatorEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

MailApp.sendEmail({
to : UserEmail,
subject: "Your project spreadsheet",
attachments: blobs
});
}


MailApp.sendEmail({
to : CreatorEmail,
subject: "Your project spreadsheet",
attachments: blobs
});
}
```

When this email is sent to the non-gmail account, say a hotmail account, the file essentially is attached as a link to a site that redirects the user to log in to a g-mail account.